# Adwords Api How to Pause Ads on Ad level

Tags: c#, google-ads-api

I am trying to PAUSE the Ads with the AdId and AdGroupID. I have successfully paused an AdGroup but i want to pause Ads individually. Is this possible on Adwords API. I tried the code below but It seems it only works on AdGroup level. Also checked the AdService but seems that there is no option to edit the Status.
I am using Ads.AdWords.v201809
Thanks in advance

```
    public void googleEnableDisableAds(AdWordsUser user, long adGroupId, long AdID, AdGroupAdStatus AdStatus)
    {
        using (AdGroupAdService adGroupAdService =
             (AdGroupAdService)user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201809.AdGroupAdService))
        {
            List<AdGroupAdOperation> operations = new List<AdGroupAdOperation>();


            // Create the expanded text ad.
            ExpandedTextAd expandedTextAd = new ExpandedTextAd
            {
                //CR[i].                              
                id = AdID
            };

            AdGroupAd expandedTextAdGroupAd = new AdGroupAd
            {
                adGroupId = adGroupId,
                ad = expandedTextAd,

                // Optional: Set the status.
                status = AdStatus
            };

            // Create the operation.
            AdGroupAdOperation operation = new AdGroupAdOperation
            {
                @operator = Operator.SET,
                operand = expandedTextAdGroupAd
            };

            operations.Add(operation);

            AdGroupAdReturnValue retVal = null;

            try
            {
                if (operations.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Create the ads.
                    retVal = adGroupAdService.mutate(operations.ToArray());

                    // Display the results.
                    if (retVal != null && retVal.value != null)
                    {
                        foreach (AdGroupAd adGroupAd in retVal.value)
                        {
                            ExpandedTextAd newAd = adGroupAd.ad as ExpandedTextAd;
                            Console.WriteLine(
                                "Expanded text ad with ID '{0}' and headline '{1} - {2}' " +
                                "was added.", newAd.id, newAd.headlinePart1, newAd.headlinePart2);
                            //adGroupId                      
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No expanded text ads were created.");
                    }
                }

                adGroupAdService.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new System.ApplicationException("Failed to create expanded text ad.", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from API docs https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/csharp/basic-operations#pause-an-ad

The key idea is to set `status` property to `PAUSED`

```
AdGroupAdStatus status = AdGroupAdStatus.PAUSED
```